# How do I call an actioncreator with details of the rendered DOM element in Flux?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

My use case:

- ComponentA renders a single ReactQuill (similar to a textarea) component
- The DOM height of ReactQuill is used by other components
- I want ComponentA to call an ActionCreator with the DOM height of
  ReactQuill. This will then update the store responsible for holding
  that data
- I have found there are three scenarios when the height of ReactQuill will change

The are:

1. When a user types in the field
2. When the browser width changes
3. On the initial creation

I have 1 and 2 working. But I can't figure out how to call the action creator on the initial creation?

I tried calling it in componentDidUpdate but it throws an error saying it is in the middle of a dispatch.

Any ideas? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `componentDidUpdate` or another lifecycle event will result in that error because Facebook's Flux implementation doesn't want actions to result in another action getting fired (I assume there was an action that resulted in your component updating). So basically you need to fire the action in another run loop.

Is there a callback you can use for when your editor is initialized? For example, if you're using Quill (although I've never used it myself nor have I tested this method), I couldn't find a callback for initialization, but I would guess you're setting the contents on initialization for which there is an event you can listen for: `text-change` (found here: http://quilljs.com/docs/events/#text-change)

```
editor.on('text-change', function(delta, source) {
  if (source == 'api') { // Maybe you want to dispatch action only when set through API
    Actions.updateEditorHeight(...);
  }
});
```

Another hacky solution which I would only use as a last resort as there is probably a better solution is using a `setTimeout` in one of the component's lifecycle events. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // init editor, perhaps load saved data
  setTimeout(function() {
    Actions.updateEditorHeight(...);
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: The text-change event doesn't trigger on create. How would I use setTimeout? I tried to do it, but I was still getting the error.

Comment: I meant you probably set the content yourself when the editor is initialized (for example to load saved data). If not, you could also initialize it with empty text so it _does_ fire on create.

For setTimeout I'll add example to the answer

Comment: The setTimeout worked. Feels a bit dirty, but I can't think of another way around it. Thanks for the help